# NodeJS Express Nunjucks: Error: template not found: frontend/home.html at createTemplate

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

```
Error: template not found: frontend/home.html
at createTemplate (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:290:15)
at next (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:330:7)
at handle (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:329:11)
at /var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:339:9
at next (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:328:7)
at Object.asyncIter (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:334:3)
at Environment.getTemplate (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:321:9)
at Environment.render (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:360:10)
at NunjucksView.render (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/nunjucks/src/express-app.js:22:9)
at tryRender (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:657:10)
at Function.render (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:609:3)
at ServerResponse.render (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
at module.home (/var/www/apps/moss/crash-game/app/controllers/web/home.js:252:21)
```

I get this error when deploying my app. On local this is working perfecting. I have even tried giving the directory permission 777 but still fails. I'm PM2 to run this on the server